# Exporting multiple sized images in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to export my iOS App Icon in different sizes but without having to do it for each size! Is there a way with Adobe Illustrator where you can export various PNG's with different sizes all in one go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an answer myself!

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html

As detailed in the link above; A script is a series of commands that tells Illustrator to perform one or more tasks.

So by using the following script I was able to export multiple images in different sizes as I wanted.

```
#target Illustrator

/**
* export multiple PNG's in different sizes
* @author Alexandros Harvey
*/
// Adapted to export an Illustrator file in various sizes by Alexandros Harvey
// based on how to export images as CSS Layers by CarlosCanto


if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    main();
}
else alert('Cancelled by user');

function main() {
    var document = app.activeDocument;
    var afile = document.fullName;
    var filename = afile.name.split('.')[0];

    var folder = afile.parent.selectDlg("Export as CSS Layers (images only)...");

    if(folder != null)
    { 
        var activeABidx = document.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex();
        var activeAB = document.artboards[activeABidx]; // get active AB        
        var abBounds = activeAB.artboardRect;// left, top, right, bottom

        var docBounds = document.visibleBounds;
        activeAB.artboardRect = docBounds;

        var options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
        options.antiAliasing = true;
        options.transparency = true;
        options.artBoardClipping = true;

        var icons = [
            {"name": "Icon-512@2x", "size":1024},
            {"name": "Icon-512",        "size":512},
            {"name": "Icon-60@3x",  "size":180},
            {"name": "Icon-76@2x",  "size":152},
            {"name": "Icon-72@2x",  "size":144},
            {"name": "Icon-60@2x",  "size":120},
            {"name": "Icon-57@2x",  "size":114},
            {"name": "Icon-50@2x",  "size":100},
            {"name": "Icon-40@2x",  "size":80},
            {"name": "Icon-76",         "size":76},
            {"name": "Icon-72",         "size":72},
            {"name": "Icon-60",         "size":60},
            {"name": "Icon-29@2x",  "size":58},
            {"name": "Icon-57",         "size":57},
            {"name": "Icon-50",         "size":50},
            {"name": "Icon-40",         "size":40},
            {"name": "Icon-29",         "size":29}
        ];

        var icon, file;
        for(var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++)
        {
            icon = icons[i]; 

            file = new File(folder.fsName + '/' + icon.name + ".png");

            // My App Icon is originally 1024x1024 so that's why I divide height and width by 1024
            options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.size / document.width);
            options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.size / document.height);

            document.exportFile(file,ExportType.PNG24,options);
        }

        activeAB.artboardRect = abBounds;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else who needs something similar.

**UPDATE:**

With regards to different sizes; Change the icons array to use height and width instead of size e.g.

```
var icons = [{"name": "Icon-512@2x", "height":250, "width":125}, ...]
```

Then change horizontalScale to use the width and verticalScale to use height. I have also changed it so it uses the document height and width rather than a hard coded number.

```
options.horizontalScale = 100 * (icon.width / document.width);
options.verticalScale = 100 * (icon.height / document.height);
```

**RUNNING THE SCRIPT:**
By [volleybologist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663732/volleybologist)

1. Copy the code above into an editor (like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/))
2. Save as a javascript file (.js)
3. Open Illustrator (checked with Illustator CC 19.1.0 and it works)
4. In Illustrator, go to File > Scripts > Other Script and open the .js file you just saved
5. A dialog will pop up, find and select the .js file
6. Another dialog will pop up which asks you to choose a location for the pngs to be exported
7. Script will run and images should be in the chosen folder